# Specified cast is not valid #3

Tags: c#

I have this issue where I am receiving "Specified cast is not valid" no errors  in the Error list inside Visual Studio. Could this error becoming from my Access Database?

```
private void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String desItem = desWork.Text;
    decimal partscost = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxPartsCost.Text);
    decimal laborhours = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxHours.Text);
    decimal laborrate = Convert.ToDecimal(textBoxRate.Text);
    decimal total = laborhours * laborrate + partscost;

    try
    {
        servicesTableAdapter.InsertServices((short?)comboBoxCustomer.SelectedValue, (DateTime?)dateTimePickerServiceDate.Value, desItem, partscost, laborhours, laborrate, total);
        MessageBox.Show("Services Inserted", "Succes!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

I think it may be coming from the `(short?)comboBoxCustomer.SelectedValue` because inside Visual Studio it's telling me I need to cast into a short but inside Access I am using  long integer. Not sure why this is the case. Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you never use `ex.Message` as a diagnostic output. Use `ex.ToString()` instead, which will show you the entire stack trace, including any inner exceptions.

Comment: Could you please give us the stack trace and the error column?

Comment: @JohnSaunders The end-user might not need to be scared by a stack trace.

Comment: @ByteBlast: I said nothing about displaying it to the end user. I was talking about _diagnostic_ output, to the developer. Besides, exception messages are not meant to be friendly, end-user error messages. "The specified cast is invalid" will mean nothing to the end user.

Comment: Are you getting a runtime error or a compile time error? Can you post the signature of your InsertServices method and SelectedValue property? If it is a compile time error, can you split the line which VS signals into shorter statements? This will help you diagnose exactly which part of your code is invalid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your conjecture is almost certainly correct.

A boxed value type may only be unboxed to *the type it actually is*. If you have a `long` in there, you can't unbox it to `short?` directly. You have to unbox it to `long` (or `long?`) first, and *then* convert it to `short?`.

This is a pretty frequently asked question. See my article on the subject for a detailed explanation.

http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/

Comment: Why is Visual Studio suggesting I should cast it `short?` then?

Comment: @ClaudeGrecea It's saying that the result you need has to be a `short?`, so you need to use some combination of casts or conversion operators to get there.  In this case, a simple cast is not appropriate

Comment: @Servy but why is the result short when the value in the database is long? Shouldn't Visual Studio use the same cast as what I depicted in Access or is VS selecting the best fit for the situation to reserve memory?